# add a Timer to an Object as3

Tags: actionscript-3

How do I add a Timer to an Object in as3 flash professional cs5?

```
var s={};
s.WTACH:Timer = new Timer(1);
```

This code produces an error:

```
1078: Label must be a simple identifier.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a problem with your declaration. Try this:

```
var s = {};
var temp:Timer = new Timer(1);
s.WATCH = temp;
```

Comment: that had crossed my mind. Why can't it be done my way, what is wrong with it?

Comment: The problem with your approach is that you were trying to define a dataType for an object property by doing `s.WTACH:Timer`. This is not valid syntax. Instead if you would had just done `s.WTACH = new Timer(1)`, it would had worked.

Comment: How come your approach does not work with s.WATCH=new Object();  ??